What scientific evidence there is that keeping cooked meat at room temperature is unsafe past two hours?
I've been part of many discussions about why it's unsafe to store cooked food at room temperature past two hours. An old question (How long can cooked food be safely stored at room/warm temperature?) links to USDA with common guidance that it is not safe to keep cooked food at room temperature for beyond 2 hours.
However, government agency policies are fairly opaque. Here are specific questions:
If meat is cooked in a slow cooker, what happens to it once it cools off and is left at room temperature for over two hours? If it was safe to eat when it was hot, what happens past two hours? How to bacteria get in (were they already in) and when do toxins form?
I am looking only for published article citations, not common sense, government recommendations, popular websites of personal experiences. Pubmed preferred but anything goes, any study that either measured toxins/bacteria or was able to correlate cases of food poisoning to food storage. US/Canada preferred.

Downvoted for "lack of research effort" on a stunningly well-covered subject. Most of it so well covered so long ago you'll need microfilm rather than pubmed to find it.

I have spent time Googling, asking AI and generally poking around. The problem is not lack of information, the problem is the noise to signal ratio, this is why I’m asking for references.

I find the formulation 'unsafe past two hours' somewhat unfortunate. The guidelines say that it is guaranteed to be safe up to two hours. To me 'not guaranteed to be safe' and 'unsafe' are not quite the same thing.

@quarague True. The guidelines are for safe, from any of a variety of organisms, all the time, if the guidelines are followed. Not 90 or 95 or 99% of the time.

@Ecnerwal Sorry, but the absolute safety is not correct. They determined an acceptable (very very small) risk and then provide guideline how to achieve that. Safe at all times from everything is simply impossible and no guideline will ever claim that. The difference between sticking to the 2 hour guideline and using 4 hours instead is the difference between 99.9% versus 99% or something like that.

asking AI The SNR was too low so you went to the noise factory, lol

@le3th4x0rbot Ironically, the one thing fancy modern LLMs are great for is finding plain-language information in a large quantity of documentation -- without needing to know the exact combination of keywords to search for. It's exactly what you need in a noisy data set. Unfortunately, you have to assume the information exists in the training data, which it likely does not for, e.g.. ChatGPT here.

@le3th4x0rbot Fully agree, just to put more emphasis on the point: NEVER ask "AI" for factual information. Moreover, NEVER EVER ask "AI" for information the safety or health of anyone depends on.

@Bloodgain Yeah, LLMs like ChatGPT are pretty good at answering obscure questions if they know the answer. Unfortunately the current generation of LLMs will also happily and confidently answer a lot of questions they don't know the answer to. (Also, they can't really tell the difference between good and bad answers very well. Even when their training data does include a relevant answer, it might be from some random person on the Internet or from a site trying to sell you snake oil.)

Picking one of many bacteria with heat-resistant spores:
Prevalence of B. cereus in meat:
https://bmcmicrobiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12866-024-03204-9
Heat resistance of B. cereus spores
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168160521004645
https://www.journalofdairyscience.org/article/S0022-0302(19)30556-9/pdf
Growth rates (which go hand in hand with toxin formation once the spore has returned to the vegetative state):
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168160597001104 (abstract only - article paywalled)
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168160521003792 (abstract only - article paywalled)
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349462015_Modeling_Bacillus_cereus_Growth_and_Cereulide_Formation_in_Cereal-_Dairy-_Meat-_Vegetable-Based_Food_and_Culture_Medium
Since you only want citations, you'll have to connect the dots yourself. Nobody got research funding to explain how heat resistant spores in your room temperature crockpot turn into unsafe food unless perhaps it was 1920-30 era research funding.
Or perhaps this rather general published article will help:
https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/32/4/579/1813157?login=true
As for the supposedly opaque intent of the USDA guidelines, they are to "protect the health of the public by providing food safety". But I'd have to refer you to a government site for that quote.
As an example of USDA responding to better data, (y'know, food science) they altered their unground meat temperature guideline for pork from 160°F to 145°F  with a 3 minute rest added back in 2011. Ground meat remained at 160°F with poultry at 165°F
This comes pretty close to being exactly on point for what you asked, for Clostridium perfringens and has 64 references to lead you further if you click through to the fulltext.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15270517/

So how does canned-meat, handle this? Is it maybe cooked at a much higher temperature, killing all spores? (The OP did say slow-cooker.)

Canned meat is pressure-canned at higher temperatures for times proven to be adequate to kill all spores - except when it isn't, and there's an outbreak - more common in home-canned than commercial products, but still happens in commercial products sometimes. Some light reading on the grand-daddy spore-former that's typically the highest concern, Clostridium botulinum: https://academic.oup.com/cid/article/66/suppl_1/S73/4780431?login=true

on another note, many countries like mine have food vendors that is kinda like chipotle or the likes with cooked chicken of fish just hanging out there from morning till , well until they are sold , respect to our body for fighting all those pathogens.

@encryptoferia we get that statement often, but it's based on false assumptions. Food safety standards are to define a safe time and temperature in a way that protects also vulnerable groups.  It doesn't mean that beyond that slot everything immediately becomes rotten. See a more lengthy elaboration here.

I cannot find any support for two hours being a dangerous period of time in any of the links you provide. (Of course, many are abstract-only, and I may have missed something.) Most of them do not contain specific time values but try to fit models to experimental data or compare various environmental and matrix conditions relative to each other. Where times are mentioned (e.g. in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349462015_Modeling_Bacillus_cereus_Growth_and_Cereulide_Formation_in_Cereal-_Dairy-_Meat-_Vegetable-Based_Food_and_Culture_Medium) they are in the 18+ hour range.

Also, a condescending remark like "nobody got research funding to explain how heat resistant spores in your room temperature crockpot turn into unsafe food unless perhaps it was 1920-30 era research funding" is inadequate and false as well: Because germination and growth speed e.g. for Bacillus cereus varies between and even within strains and is highly dependent on a host of environmental and growth matrix conditions there is clearly room and funding for ongoing quantitative research, which is what the OP asked for.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Isn't that what the links provide?
